# Is it possible to call the java webservices using CronTab?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws, cron

I have implemented the web services in Java using JaxRS and HIbernate in JBoss 6, and now the requirement is to update the database in interval of every 15 minutes , so having an idea  to do  it in crontab , btw i would like to know  about is it possible to call the webservice  from crontab, Please let me know the methods to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see the following ways to call it:

1. you can write a bash script using curl, or java app, or any other app, so cron will execute it to call your webservice.
   an example is [here](http://en.newinstance.it/2008/11/11/calling-webservice-at-the-unix-command-line/)
2. you can call your webservice using jboss-managed scheduler. an example is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Quartz_scheduler_integration.html)